# How does type.__call__ know the type of its result?

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass

I'd like to ask of the following fragment of code:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __call__(self, *args):
        obj = super().__call__(*args)
        print('Meta specific __call__ actions')
        return obj

class Spam(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print('Spam.__init__(%r)' % args)
```

How does super().__call__ (super() means 'type' here?) know it should
create an instance of class Spam? __call__ gets no arguments which
would help it.

Spam is an instance of Meta, thus Spam() shall invoke
Meta.__call__. My reasoning stops here. Spam('foo') shall create an
instance of Spam. Please explain how in the Meta.__call__ method this
information is obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spam is an instance of Meta, this instance is passed in the `self` parameter to `Meta.__call__`.

The `super()` construct will pass the value of `self` along to the base method; so `type.__call__` will get passed `Spam` via its `self` parameter.